# .NET - Buffer overflow

Tags: .net, windows-xp, buffer-overflow

I've a .NET application that is crashing a couple of times a day, in our production env, I'm running process monitor on an effected PC and its reporting buffer overflows in the following location attached (had to remove image).

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2E12&SUBSYS_04201028&REV_03\3&172e68dd&0&10\HardwareID

Its plagued with them, 304 in 2 hours.

From research the device causing the issue is the Intel Corporation - 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller, should I update the drivers for this controller.

Comment: Since the driver is blowing up you should always remove it check to see if the problem reappears with another. It could be a hardware issue, or your code might be calling a library routine that you could mitigate. There are many things to consider.